# Fix powerline-shell bash prompt (mode: 'compatible' or mode: 'patched')

Tags: bash, shell, fonts, powerline-statusline

### Background

I have problems with [`powerline-shell`](https://github.com/b-ryan/powerline-shell) prompts; for some reason I can't find any way to build the graphical `>` powerline character.

I installed the python powerline json config with:

```shell
$ mkdir -p ~/.config/powerline-shell && \
powerline-shell --generate-config > ~/.config/powerline-shell/config.json
```

FWIW, I'm using putty to ssh into my systems.  Whether I set `$TERM` to `xterm-256color` or `putty` makes no difference in the powerline prompt rendering.

---

#### My `~/.config/powerline-shell/config.json` contents...

Obviously, this configuration uses `mode: flat` to workaround the `>` rendering problems.

```shell
$  cat ~/.config/powerline-shell/config.json

{
  "mode": "flat",
  "segments": [
    "virtual_env",
    "aws_profile",
    "ssh",
    "cwd",
    "git",
    "git_stash",
    "jobs",
    "set_term_title",
    "svn",
    "newline",
    "root"
  ],
  "cwd": {
    "mode": "flat"
  },
  "theme": "default"
}
```

---

#### Render `powerline-shell` with mode: flat

When I use `"mode": "flat",` in `~/.config/powerline-shell/config.json`, the prompt looks fine... one should note that `flat` prompt mode does not use a graphical `>` character...

[image: powerline_with_mode_flat]

---

#### Render `powerline-shell` with mode: compatible

When I use `"mode": "patched"` or `"mode": "compatible"` in `~/.config/powerline-shell/config.json`, *the graphical `>` character is required and does not seem to exist (see NOTE at the bottom)*.

[image: powerline_with_mode_patched]

---

### Question

How can I fix this `powerline-shell` prompt install to use `mode:` `compatible` or `patched`?

I installed a central `powerline-shell` script in `/opt/bin/powerline-shell` which is called with the full `/opt` path whenever it's used.

#### My `.bashrc` contents...

```shell
$ cat ~/.bashrc

# .bashrc - Always executed for a new shell, unlike .bash_profile,
#           which normally isn't run for terms without the -ls option

export PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-shared"

# I built a custom vim-9.0 in /opt/vim90
export VIMRUNTIME="/opt/vim90/runtime/"

# Run a whois query that retrieves info from Team CYMRU about an IP
function cwhois_fn {
    whois -h whois.cymru.com " -v $1"
}

# Use vi for term line edits
set -o vi


## Bash history hacks
##  http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48116/6766
HISTSIZE=2000
HISTFILESIZE=$HISTSIZE
HISTCONTROL=ignorespace:ignoredups
HISTTIMEFORMAT="%y-%m-%d %T "
#function history {
#  _bash_history_sync
#  builtin history "$@"
#}
function _bash_history_sync {
  builtin history -a         #1
  HISTFILESIZE=$HISTSIZE     #2
  builtin history -c         #3
  builtin history -r         #4
}
export PROMPT_COMMAND=_bash_history_sync

export TERM="xterm-256color"

# Set a default bash prompt...
#PS1='[\u@\h \W]\$ '

function _update_ps1() {
    PS1=$(/opt/bin/powerline-shell $?)
}

#if [[ $TERM != linux && ! $PROMPT_COMMAND =~ _update_ps1 ]]; then
if [[ $TERM != linux && ! $PROMPT_COMMAND =~ _update_ps1 ]]
then
    PROMPT_COMMAND="_update_ps1; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
    export PROMPT_COMMAND
else
    export PS1='[\u@\h \W]\$ '
    export PROMPT_COMMAND="$PS1"
fi

export PS1 HISTFILESIZE HISTTIMEFORMAT HISTCONTROL HISTSIZE

# Get the LOCAL aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc.local ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc.local
fi

###############################################################################
#
# Use the following to initialize Debian for powerline installation...
#    > sudo apt-get install fonts-powerline
#    > sudo apt-get install fonts-hack
#    > sudo apt-get install powerline
#
# Use the following to install under Debian...
#    https://github.com/b-ryan/powerline-shell
#    > git clone https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts
#    > cd nerd-fonts
#    > rm -rf .git      # the .git directory is massive!
#    > ./install.sh
#
# Use the following to initialize MacOS for the powerline installation...
#    https://github.com/b-ryan/powerline-shell
#    > brew tap homebrew/cask
#    > brew install fontforge
#    > git clone https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts
#    > cd nerd-fonts
#    > rm -rf .git        # the .git directory is massive!
#    > ./install.sh
#
###############################################################################
```

#### `/opt/bin/powerline-shell` contents...

```python
#!/opt/virtual_env/py39_test/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys
from powerline_shell import main as powerline_main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(powerline_main())
```

Comment: "Squares are missing characters" – This indicates the font you're using misses the needed glyph(s). *I guess* there is nothing to fix on the remote end; your local terminal emulator gets the right sequence of bytes but is unable to render the character you expected. Tell PuTTY to use a better font. Not an answer because neither I have tested this nor I know which font you should use.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working with `mode: patched` (ref `~/.config/powerline-shell/config.json` below) on my Debian 11 system...

- Specific commands...

  - `sudo apt-get install fonts-powerline fonts-hack powerline`
  - `pip install powerline-shell`
  - `git clone https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts; cd nerd-fonts; rm -rf .git; install.sh; # install.sh installs the nerd-fonts`
  - My `~/.bashrc` additions / changes:

```bash
function _update_ps1() {
    # /opt/bin/powerline-shell should be manually-installed
    #     see the script at the bottom of this superuser answer
    PS1=$(/opt/bin/powerline-shell $?)
}

export TERM="xterm-256color"

if [[ $TERM != linux && ! $PROMPT_COMMAND =~ _update_ps1 ]]
then
    PROMPT_COMMAND="_update_ps1; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
    export PROMPT_COMMAND
else
    export PS1='[\u@\h \W]\$ '
    export PROMPT_COMMAND="$PS1"
fi
```

- My contents of `~/.config/powerline-shell/config.json`:

```json
{
  "mode": "patched",
  "segments": [
    "virtual_env",
    "aws_profile",
    "ssh",
    "cwd",
    "git",
    "git_stash",
    "jobs",
    "set_term_title",
    "svn",
    "newline",
    "root"
  ],
  "cwd": {
    "mode": "patched"
  },
  "theme": "default"
}
```

- My contents of `/opt/bin/powerline-shell`:

```python
#!/opt/virtual_env/py39_test/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys
from powerline_shell import main as powerline_main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(powerline_main())
```